On Viber, the camera device is missing and app notifications are not working
I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 3. In Viber which download from .deb package, when I try to make a video call, it says "video hardware not found." Additionally, app notifications are not working, so I do not receive notifications for calls and messages.

How did you install Viber? Edit your question with the details.

Install from .deb package
